The behavior of aws-sdk-go sub-loglevel?
I set the AWS SDK log level to aws.LogDebugWithRequestRetries:
session.NewSessionWithOptions(
    session.Options{
        Config:   *aws.NewConfig().WithLogger(aws.LoggerFunc(logrus.WithField("from", "aws-sdk").Info)).WithLogLevel(aws.LogDebugWithRequestRetries).WithMaxRetries(3),
    })

According to the help doc, this log level "should be used to log when you want to log when service requests are being retried. Will also enable LogDebug.", when I set this log level, I saw lots of other logs like DEBUG: Request dynamodb/PutItem Details:\n. If I just want the error log from AWS SDK when retry happens, how to achieve that? Thanks.
